# NGINX: Reverse proxy from location to port

Tags: laravel, nginx

on `/etc/nginx/sites-available/x.x.x.x.conf`, I have this entry:

```
   location /myapp {
       alias /var/www/html/myapp/public;
       index index.php;
       try_files $uri $uri/ @myapp;
 
       location ~* \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 7200;
       }
 
   }
 
   location @myapp {
             rewrite /myapp/(.*)$ /myapp/index.php?/$1 last;
   }
```

currently I visit my website to x.x.x.x/myapp

How do I proxy it to x.x.x.x:8059?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your problem. Why don't ppl post their server blocks? I try anyway:

```
    location /myapp/
    {
        proxy_pass http://x.x.x.x:8059/;
    }
```

Or the other way round:

```
server
{
    listen 8059;
    server_name x.x.x.x example.org www.example.org;

    # …

    location /
    {
        proxy_pass http://x.x.x.x:80/myapp/;
    }
}
```

It can easily happen that now your paths are broken. Change them in code or check out `proxy_redirect` and `sub(s)_filter` for on-the-fly changes.

Browser -> Key [F12] -> Console and/or Network is always helpful.

Also nice on Windows: Install Git, open Git Bash and do a `curl -IL <URL>`.

Comment: at the end of the day, I create new server entry on the `.conf` and it works flawlessly. thanks